# Validate a text and number format using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate an identification format using Java.

Examples: `UWU/CST/14/0015` or `UWU/IIT/14/0025`

Here UWU is required, and one of CST or IIT must be present else it is invalid. After that it can have any two digits and then at least four digits in the last section. Please help me in solving this.

```
package validate2;

import java.util.*;
public class Validate2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
    String l=a.next();
    boolean x=l.matches("^uwu\\/\\w\\w\\w\\/\\d\\d\\/\\d\\d\\d\\d");

    if (x == false) {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Enter a valid serviceNO");
        System.out.println("NO");
        //return false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("YES");
        //return true;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Case sensitive ?

Comment: @Rahul yeas mate..help me to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex:

```
^UWU\/(CST|IIT)\/\d{2}\/\d{4,}$
```

- Ensures it starts with `UWU`
- Ensures second part is either `CST` or `IIT`
- Ensures the third part contains *exactly 2 digits* `\d{2}`
- Ensures the last part contains *4 or more digits* `\d{4,}`

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Os15IQ/1)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this regex `(?i)UWU\/(CST|IIT)/\d{2}\/\d{4}` :

```
String str = "UWU/CST/14/0015";
String regex = "(?i)UWU\\/(CST|IIT)/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}";
System.out.println(str.matches(regex));
```

---

1. `(?i)` : will accept any upper or lower case
2. `UWU`  : start with `UWU`
3. `(CST|IIT)` : followed by CST or IIT
4. `\d{2}` : followed by 2 degits
5. `\d{4}` : followed by 4 degits

Answer (score 1):

Well instead of this long regex `^uwu\\/\\w\\w\\w\\/\\d\\d\\/\\d\\d\\d\\d`

Here is the simplest one.

**Regex:** `^UWU\/(?:CST|IIT)\/\d+\/\d+$`

**Explanation:** Starting with literal `UWU` followed by `/` followed by either `CST` or `IIT` followed by `/` `multiple digits` then `/` then `multiple digits`.

To restrict no of digits use `{n,m}` where `n` is minimum no and `m` is max.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QB7z9O/1/)**